# How to intergrate semBCreate(VxWorks) and sem_init(Linux) signal function

Tags: c, linux, vxworks

I have a task that , i have a large code based on Vxworks, now I want to migrate it to Linux C language. My aim is to not change my original code, just like the below:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_IN_LINUX
pid = semBCreate(int arg1, long int arg2){
    sem_init(&pid, int arg1, long int arg2);
}
#endif
```

I know that is wrong, because Vxworks's semBCreate have only 2 args, but sem_init(Linux) need 3 args, The above code is used to express my purpose. I must use Vxworks' function name to keep my original code(semBCreate),but  realize the sem_init function.
How to finish??????Please help me, thank you!!!!!

Comment: What you've written isn't valid C code (e.g., calling a function with `int arg1`).  Could you double-check your code?  Also, `sem_init` takes a `sem_t*` as the first argument whereas it appears that you're passing a `pid_t*`.

Comment: Have you seen: [White paper: RTOS Migration](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=a86c535364566e252181bfab3feba80ed2b56940) It has sections on how to port from VxWorks to Linux APIs

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run the code, but I would try something like this:

```
typedef int SEM_ID;

typedef struct
{
   // mapping the VxWorks semaphore ID with the Linux semaphore data
   SEM_ID semId;
   sem_t sem;
}semData;

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_SEMAPHORES 100
semData semaphors[MAX_NUMBER_OF_SEMAPHORES]; // must be initialized with 0

SEM_ID semBCreate(int options, SEM_B_STATE initialState)
{
   int i = 0;
   for(; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_SEMAPHORES; i++)
   {
      if(semaphors[i].semId == 0)
         break; // free space for new semaphore found
   }

   if(i == MAX_NUMBER_OF_SEMAPHORES)
      return 0; // no free space for new semaphore

   // Since VxWorks semaphores only work within the same process, the second
   // parameter can be set to 0.
   // The value of the third parameter is the same as in VxWorks (0 or 1 for binary semaphore).
   if(sem_init(&semaphors[i].sem, 0, (unsigned int)initialState) != 0)
      return 0; // creating semaphore failed

   semaphors[i].semId = i + 1;
   return semaphors[i].semId; // creating semaphore successfull
}

STATUS semTake(SEM_ID semId, int timeout)
{
   semData *semaphore = getSemaphore(semId);
   if(semaphore == NULL)
      return ERROR; // semaphore not found

   // I assumed 1 tick to be 1ms. If not, more calculation is needed!
   struct timespec tout;
   tout.tv_sec = timeout / 1000;
   tout.tv_nsec = (timeout % 1000) * 1000000;
   
   if(sem_timedwait(&semaphore->sem, &tout) != 0)
      return ERROR;
   
   return OK;
}

STATUS semGive(SEM_ID semId)
{
   semData *semaphore = getSemaphore(semId);
   if(semaphore == NULL)
      return ERROR; // semaphore not found

   if(sem_post(&semaphore->sem) != 0)
      return ERROR;
   
   return OK;
}

static semData* getSemaphore(SEM_ID semId)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_SEMAPHORES; i++)
   {
      if(semaphors[i].semId == semId)
         return &semaphors[i]; // semaphore found
   }

   return NULL; // semaphore not found
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea how it could work!